# View controller in Storyboard loading differently

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

Opened a old project to work in xCode 9.2 the storyboard loaded successfully .but the view-controller in it are loading differently have a look below image

[image]

the tiny blue things are actually viewcontroller used in the app .Any Help will be greatly appreciated as quite strange for me .

as need it to-open normally .

BTW project is three years old

storyboard screen shot
[image: d]

Comment: Please look at where the small view controllers originate from. Could it be that they are (or descend from) embedded view controllers? In that case the constraints/size for the view controller container is the problem.

Comment: I do not understand what your question is. Do you wonder why the table looks different in the storyboard than in your running application?

Comment: @AndreasOetjen  above screenshot is of storyboard which contains Different view controllers as you can see Two view controllers in the  storyboard are showing fine but rest of the view Controllers are tiny blue (are actually view controllers )

Comment: @LGP please check my above comment

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, I want to see _where_ the lines go from the small view controllers. They come from somewhere, and I suspect their origin has to do with your problem.

Comment: @LGP no need to say sorry ,as Even i am unclear .as i just opened the project  and then the storyboardfor view updates.please check the new image added in the question for storyboard screenshot

Comment: Now I see it. :) However, they all seem to still originate outside the image. One trail of view controllers is at bottom left, then seems to go even further left. Another trail goes beyond top middle of the image. Are they embedded in a very small view controller container at the end?